# JOIN a products table to price change table using job date

Tags: mysql

I have a jobs table which looks something like this:

```
**jobs**

 job_id | customer_id | date
------------------------------------
|    1  |           1 | 2012-01-03 |
|    2  |           2 | 2013-02-04 |
|    3  |           1 | 2013-03-05 |
|    4  |           3 | 2013-05-04 |
```

Then I have a products table which looks something like this:

```
**products**

 product_id | description | price
-----------------------------------
|         1 |      prod_1 | 25.50 | 
|         2 |      prod_2 | 34.95 |
```

And finally when prices are changed I have a product_price_changes table like this:

```
**product_price_changes**

 price_change_id | product_id | price_change_date | old_price
---------------------------------------------------------------
|              1 |          1 |        2013-01-01 |     20.00 |
|              2 |          1 |        2013-02-05 |     23.00 |
```

with a UNIQUE INDEX on (product_id,price_change_date)

I want to create a VIEW which grabs the product pricing reflecting the prices from the date the job was done.

which, with the data above, should create a table like this:

```
**view_job_pricing**

 job_id | product_id | price
------------------------------
|     1 |          1 | 20.00 |
|     1 |          2 | 34.95 |
|     2 |          1 | 23.00 |
|     2 |          2 | 34.95 |
|     3 |          1 | 25.50 |
|     3 |          2 | 34.95 |
|     4 |          1 | 25.50 |
|     4 |          2 | 34.95 |
```

So it should select the product price change with the highest date, which is still less than the job date, if it exists, otherwise it should grab the current product price.

I have this which works:

```
CREATE VIEW view_job_pricing 
AS
SELECT j.job_id, p.product_id, MAX(price_change_date), 
       IFNULL(ppc.old_price,p.price) AS price
FROM products p
JOIN jobs j
LEFT JOIN product_price_changes ppc 
          ON p.product_id = ppc.product_id AND date < price_change_date
GROUP BY job_id, product_id;
```

But it is a pretty slow on the real database (far more jobs and products). Just wondering if there is a better way. Thanks!

Comment: index the date field!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this as a correlated subquery.  You are allowed subqueries in the `select` clause of a view, and the correlated subquery should use the index on product.

```
CREATE VIEW view_job_pricing 
AS
SELECT j.job_id, p.product_id, MAX(price_change_date), 
       coalesce((select ppc.price
                 from product_price_changes ppc
                 where p.product_id = ppc.product_id AND j.date < ppc.price_change_date
                 order by ppc.price_change_date desc
                 limit 1
                ),
                p.price) AS price
FROM products p cross join
     jobs j
```

You can simplify the processing and improve the performance by changing the structure of the `product_price_changes` table.  Instead of having only an effective_date, also have an end_date.  With `effdate` and `enddate` columns, the query would be much faster and simpler.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize I could use subqueries in the SELECT clause of a view.. I will give it a try.. I'm glad I asked

Comment: If I do add those columns to product_price_changes, is there a way to add a unique key to the product_id, date_span combination?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to indexing all the involved columns, and checking your indexing results using `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` (which you can post here for review), you can try speeding up the view by defining it as `CREATE ALGORITHM = MERGE VIEW`. There are a number of restrictions on when this can be done, so YMMV

[http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html][1]